# What is the difference between 'in' and 'is' when used in an 'if' statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I just started Python two days ago and I came across 2 types of `if` statements: one where `is` was used and another where `in` was used. So what is basically the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **is** keyword is used to test if two variables refer to the same object.
Example:

```
x = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
y = x
print(x is y)
```

The **in** keyword is used to check if a value is present in a sequence (list, range, string etc.).  Example:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

if "banana" in fruits:
  print("yes")
```

Those are not "part" of an IF statement per-se.